# Error: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

when adding this code, this error appears, I tried adding beans:beans to the tag, but then the same error appears, please help me solve this problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="testBean"
        class="alishev.spring.demo.TestBean">
        <constructor-arg value="Neil"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: What is the error? Add the error into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are having `xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"` which means you need to prefix `beans:` to all tags from that namespace.

Remove the `:beans` from `xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"` so your XML should be as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="testBean"
        class="alishev.spring.demo.TestBean">
        <constructor-arg value="Neil"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but the problem remained with this error and the error "Downloading external resources is disabled." on line 6

Comment: @ЕгорЧистяков That's a new issue. How are you running the application? Is it a maven/gradle application? Have you added the necessary dependencies?